Solving $0=\frac {-2}{(x-1)^2}$.
$0=\frac {-2}{(x-1)^2}$
According to derivativecalculator.com, this is not solvable (has no zeros). I would agree with the website by following reasoning:
multiplying both sides by $(x-1)^2$ would give 0=-2 which is a contradiction so the restriction $0=\frac {-2}{(x-1)^2}$ cannot exist.
BUT
if you think about in terms of limits,
the fraction can only tend to zero if the denominator $(x-1)^2$ tends to infinity. therefore $(x-1) $ tends to infinity and so x tends to infinity+1. so x is infinity. But that defies the 1st set of reasoning!So there does exist a solution, just infinitely large!
Right? Or maybe I am wasting space. My problem is I just want to know which is correct. It sounds dumb, I know.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

There is no such number as infinity

An easier example of your point is that $\lim_{x -> \infty} \frac{1}{x}=0$, but for any particular value of x, $\frac{1}{x}$ is not equal to 0. You have noticed that a function may have a limit at a point, without ever reaching that point!
